# ecs does not assign container instance to pending task

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

My ecs service is configured to run a task definition with 0.399 CPU units and 0.399 GB of Memory on a t2.micro instance (1GB RAM, 1 vCPU. The task definition is configured to run in awsvpc network mode.

I want to set up a rolling update, thus I set up load balancing with a application load balancer for the service.
I use github actions to update and deploy an updated task definition using the `aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition@v1` and `aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1` actions.
What happens is that the task definition is updated and the task is created, however it is stuck in pending state. In the service event log the only message regarding this action is "service XY has started 1 tasks: task .". There are no error events or error logs.
What I notice is that, other then the running task, the newly created one has no container instance assigned.

I stumbled over the ECS -> Account Settings -> AWSVPC Trunking feature and enabled it, killed the EC2 Instance in order to apply the changes, but still my task does not reach running state.

I also tried to change the network mode of the task definition to "bridge", but then I didn't figure out how to setup my load balancing and even if that worked it would only have been a guess.

How could I get the rolling update deployment running?